# Flexbox и justify-content для единого элемента

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Хочу сделать меню, используя flexbox. 
Для меню в шапке сделал `justify-content: flex-end;`
Хочу сделать логотип по другую сторону от меню, но `justify-content: flex-start;` нельзя применить к единому элементу. 
Ставил ширину для меню и `margin-right: auto;` для логотипа, не помогло. Использовал `align-self`, тоже не помогло. Что делать? 
Отдельное спасибо за помощь в структурировании кода. Только учусь веб-разработке и голова плохо варит.

Должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При масштабировании получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: #7F1143;
}

.main,
.nav {
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
}

a:not(.logo):not(.contacts) {
  border-right: 1px solid #979797;
}

.nav {
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="logo">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <div class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <li><a class="contacts" href="#">Contacts</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Небольшие советы:**
Во-первых, не следует вкладывать `div` как ребёнка `ul`. Если честно, то вообще только `div` обходиться вместо `ul` и `li`.
Во-вторых, `margin-right: auto;` будет работать только для ребёнка (child), а не произвольного потомка (ancestor), поэтому класс `logo` надо навесить на `li`, а не на `a`.
В-третьих, не надо использовать вендорные префиксы `-webkit` для того, что уже давно работает без них, так как вряд ли вам нужно поддерживать старые версии Chrome, потому что flexbox уже относительно давно стандарт.

Код:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main,
.nav {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #7F1143;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-container {
  margin-right: auto;
}

a:not(.logo):not(.contacts) {
  border-right: 1px solid #979797;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="logo-container"><a class="logo">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class='contacts' href="#">Contacts</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Либо задайте логотип как position: relative;
Либо используйте display: inline-flex; justify-content: space-between;
где у всех элементов нужно указать flex-basis: в% соотношении относительно всего блока.
Правило display: inline-flex; применяется к родительскому элементу, так же как и justify-content: space-between;